Smoother movement of: Stop the slider/indicator on target area (timing game)
Im starting out as a SwiftUI Xcode developer and I somehow can't get this fixed and it's so annoying. Basically the below code is a kind of timing game where you have to try to stop the slider/indicator on the green rectangle. That's when you win. This already works, but the movement of the slider/indicator is so slow and just not smooth, and every time I change around certain numbers, the slider/indicator behaves very weirdly. I just want it to be fast enough so it's a challenge and I also want a very smooth movement. I tried with other animation variants, but I then I cant get the exact positioning of the slider/indicator when its stopped.
import SwiftUI

struct Slider: View {
    @State private var sliderPosition: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var isSliding: Bool = false
    @State private var didWin: Bool = false
    @State private var didYellow: Bool = false
    @State private var movingRight: Bool = true
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.01, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    let mainRectWidth: CGFloat = 300
    let targetZoneStart: CGFloat = 125
    let targetZoneWidth: CGFloat = 50
    let targetZoneStart2: CGFloat = 75
    let targetZoneWidth2: CGFloat = 150
    let sliderSpeed: CGFloat = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: mainRectWidth, height: 50)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                    .frame(width: targetZoneWidth2, height: 50)
                    .offset(x: targetZoneStart2)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: targetZoneWidth, height: 50)
                    .offset(x: targetZoneStart)
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: 10, height: 50)
                    .offset(x: sliderPosition)
                    .animation(.linear(duration: 0.01), value: sliderPosition)
                    .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                        if isSliding {
                            if movingRight {
                                sliderPosition += sliderSpeed
                                if sliderPosition >= mainRectWidth - 10 {
                                    movingRight = false
                                }
                            } else {
                                sliderPosition -= sliderSpeed
                                if sliderPosition <= 0 {
                                    movingRight = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                if isSliding {
                    isSliding = false
                    checkIfWin()
                    checkIfYellow()
                }
            }
            if didWin {
                Text("You Win!")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
            } else if didYellow && !didWin {
                Text("You Yellow!")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            } else if !didYellow && !didWin {
                Text("You Lose!")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            if !isSliding {
                Button(action: startGame) {
                    Text("Start")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func checkIfWin() {
        if sliderPosition >= targetZoneStart && sliderPosition <= (targetZoneStart + targetZoneWidth) {
            didWin = true
        }
    }

    func checkIfYellow() {
        if sliderPosition >= targetZoneStart2 && sliderPosition <= (targetZoneStart2 + targetZoneWidth2) {
            didYellow = true
        }
    }

    func startGame() {
        sliderPosition = 0
        isSliding = true
        didWin = false
        didYellow = false
        movingRight = true
    }
}

struct Slider_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Slider()
    }
}

I tried everything but I cant get it to work.

The movement is actually smoother if you remove the .animation modifier completely. On a simulator (iPhone15 running iOS 17.5) it is then pretty smooth.

No way it was that easy haha. Thanks so much!!!!!
